# Script in crontab to be executed only if is equal or exceeds a value

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rsync

I currently have a script in crontab for rsync (and some other small stuff). Right now the script is executed every 5 minutes. I modified the script to look for a specific line from the rsync part (example from my machine, not the actual code):

```
#!/bin/bash

Number=`/usr/bin/rsync -n --stats -avz -e ssh 1/ root@127.0.0.1 | grep "Number of regular files transferred" | cut -d':' -f 2 | tr -d 040\054\012`
echo $Number
```

Let's say the number is 10. If the number is 10 or below I want the script executed through the crontab. But if the number is bigger I want to be executed ONLY manually.

Any ides?

Comment: Can't you just add a `if $Number < 10` in your bash file and run it every 5 minute ? I don't really understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use an argument to execute it manually, for example:

```
if [[ $Number -le 10 || $1 == true ]];then
    echo "executing script..."
fi
```

This will execute if `$Number` is less or equal to `10` or if you execute it with `true` as the first positional argument, so if `$Number` is greater than `10` it won't execute in your crontab and you can execute your script manually with `./your_script true`.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. Thank you!